Mock ActivatedRoute breaks Router createUrlTree when using relativeTo parent
I'm having trouble mocking ActivatedRoute with a valid parent property. I've tried a myriad of combinations on the providers metadata property of TestBed.configureTestingModule() similar to:
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: ActivatedRoute,
            useValue: {
                parent: {snapshot: {}},
                snapshot: {},
                params: {}
            },
        }
    ]
}

Given a value of 1 on the someId variable, the following code snippet:
const reconciliationUrl = this.router.createUrlTree(
    [someId, 'some-action']
).toString();

produces the following expected result 1/some-action.
After changing to:
const reconciliationUrl = this.router.createUrlTree(
    [someId, 'some-action'],
    { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent }
).toString();

the result is always /.
How can I effectively mock ActivatedRoute so that the call to createUrlTree generates a url string considering [someId, 'some-action'] commands without reset it to /?
